# Hyperlink with relative url does not respond

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

OK so I am trying to build my own website using HTML templates and well i created a few additional pages of my own to incorporate to the template however and I linked them together well i thought i did and when i click the button linked to my created pages it does nothing it does not even refresh the page.

ill put a snippet of the part of the code i have problems with

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 course_col">
  <div class="course">
    <div class="course_image"><img src="images/Physics.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="course_body">
      <div class="course_title"><a href="Physics_Grade_12.html">Physics</a></div>
      <div class="course_info">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Grade 1.html">Edward Nkadimeng</a></li>
          <li><a href="Grade_12.html">Grade 12</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="course_text">
        <p>Physics Curriclum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you hover the `<a>`, do you see the target in the bottom left corner of the browser window? When you click the link, does the URL in the address bar change? Did you check the console for error messages (press F12)? Are you using any (custom) scripts?

Comment: Yes the target is present when i hover.

Comment: the links work in your snippet...so.... what Chris said.

Comment: Yeah I am getting a SEC7134: Resource not allowed error.